# Adding circles on a function plot depending on the slope

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color

I have the following function and I use manipulate to change the plot of the function and the integral respectively. In nonlinear dynamics one plots a little circle/point on the intersections of the (left) graph with the x-axis. If the slope at the point of intersection is negative the circle/point is black, if the slope is positive, the point is white.

I want to do the same (only for the left graph), but dependent on the **magnitude** of the slope at the point of intersection (with the x-axes), I want to **color** the circles continuously, e.g. light green for a small negative slope at this point, getting more and more dark as the magnitude of the slope becomes more negative and the same for a positive slope e.g. red.

Any help appreciated!

```
 f[x_, a_, b_] := a x - b x^3

Manipulate[{Plot[f[x, a, b], {x, -2, 2}], 
  n = -\[Integral]f[x, a, b] \[DifferentialD]x; 
  Plot[n, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic]}, {{a, 1/2, 
   "control parameter"}, -1, 2, 
  0.1}, {{b, 1/4, "control parameter 2"}, -1, 2, 0.1}]
```

Comment: …and if the curve is tangent to the $x$-axis, what color do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might you be looking for this?

The modifications are in the addition of the `zeros` table (though it would be much better to write down an analytical expression) and the rule for `Epilog` acts on it accordingly to generate the points. In my example, though, they are black for a small slope and become brighter red/green for larger negative/positive slopes. You can modify the arguments of the `RGBColor` function to adjust coloring to your needs.

```
Manipulate[
    {
     zeros = {#, (1/2 (Derivative[1, 0, 0][f])[#, a, b])} & /@
        (x /. NSolve[f[x, a, b] == 0, x, Reals]);

  Plot[f[x, a, b], {x, -2, 2}, 
   Epilog -> (Flatten@
        {PointSize[Large], 
         RGBColor[
           HeavisideTheta[-Last@#] (-Last@#), 
           HeavisideTheta[Last@#] Last@#,
           0],
         Point[{First@#, 0}]} & /@ zeros)],

  n = -\[Integral] f[x, a, b] \[DifferentialD] x;

  Plot[n, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Automatic]},
  {{a, 1/2, "control parameter"}, -1, 2,  0.1},
  {{b, 1/4, "control parameter 2"}, -1, 2, 0.1}]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant, thank you!

Comment: One more possible color function: `Blend[{Green, White, Red}, 1/(1 + Exp[-x])]`.